# Django throwing improper database configuration error

Tags: python, django, database, configuration

So I posted earlier about some problems with Django, but that wasn't able to be solved. I changed my approach after that. Here is the problem that I am currently facing. Whenever I try to run this script it throws this error...

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 21, in complain
     raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

This seems to be happening after I moved my import and export a csv version of the db scripts to the main project folder as opposed to an app folder. This is what the code currently looks like...

```
# exports db as a csv file

import sys, os
#sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/swen261/masterProject/HealthNet'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'HealthNet.settings'
import django
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
django.setup()
print(sys.path)
from django.db import models
from main_site.models import *

print("Starting DB export script...\n")

print("Creating csv file 'csv_output.csv'...\n")
with open('csv_output.csv', 'w+') as file:
    print("Writing out Patients...\n")
for p in Patient.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("Patient", p.user.username, p.user.password, p.user.first_name, p.user.last_name, p.hospital.name, p.insurance_provider, p.insurance_id, "nil"))
print("Writing out Doctors...\n")
for d in Doctor.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("Doctor", d.user.username, d.user.password, d.user.first_name, d.user.last_name, d.hospital.name, "nil","nil","nil"))
print("Writing out Nurses...\n")
for n in Nurse.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("Nurse", n.user.username, n.user.password, n.user.first_name, n.user.last_name, n.hospital.name, "nil", "nil", "nil"))
print("Writing out Hospital Admins...\n")
for ha in HospitalAdmin.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("HospitalAdmin", ha.user.username, ha.user.password, ha.user.first_name, ha.user.last_name, ha.hospital.name, "nil", "nil", "nil"))

print("Finished creating csv.\n")
```

This is the pertinent section of settings.py

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

And this is the directory structure...

[image: Directory structure]

Does anyone have any idea as to how to stop that from happening. The script reaches the first Patient.objects.all(), and then throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```

configure Django with default settings (not Your app settings).

### Solution 1

```
from HealthNet import settings as my_settings
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(default_settings=my_settings)
```

### Solution 2

Remove following lines:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
django.setup()
```

Django uses autoconfigure using `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable.